# MongoDB LINQ ContainsAny Unsupported Filter

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, linq

I'm refactoring away from the .NET Legacy MongoDB Drivers.  I've got a query that's written using the Legacy API's ContainsAny() method.  In the query below affectedFormFieldIds is a list of IDs.

This Throws an ArgumentException stating that this is an Unsupported Filter.

```
Queryable<FormSectionColumnLayoutReadModel>().Where(x => x.Fields.ContainsAny(affectedFormFieldsIds));
```

How do I rewrite this query using the new API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's

```cs
Queryable<FormSectionColumnLayoutReadModel>()
  .Where(x => affectedFormFieldsIds.Any(a => x.Fields.Contains(a)));
```

Comment: It works!  Thankf for the speedy response.  So speedy I can't actually accept your answer for another 7 mins.